# Error on creating invoice using APIs from Postman and salesforce

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I'm trying to create an invoice record from Postman and Salesforce and from both the places I'm getting error.
To me it looks like a syntax error, but couldn't find it

In Postman Invoice Create, I'm passing below body:

```
{
  "Line": [
    {
      "Amount": 100.00,
      "DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail",
      "SalesItemLineDetail": {
        "ItemRef": {
          "value": "1",
          "name": "Services"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "CustomerRef": {
    "value": "58"
  }
}
```

But I'm getting this error:

> {"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"Error parsing
> query","Detail":"QueryParserError:
> null","code":"4000","element":"Query"}],"type":"ValidationFault"},"time":"2021-05-01T09:07:03.252-07:00"}

In Salesforce I'm using below code to create invoice:

```
Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        request.setEndpoint('https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/462081dsfdsfsfds550/query?minorversion=56');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
        request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/text');
        request.setHeader('Authorization', authorization);
        request.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer sessionId');
        string body = '{"Line": [{"DetailType": "SalesItemLineDetail","Amount": 100.0,"SalesItemLineDetail": {"ItemRef": {"name": "Services", "value": "1"}}}], "CustomerRef": {"value": "58"}}';
request.setBody(body);        
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
```

I'm getting below error for this:

```
{"Fault":{"Error":[{"Message":"Error parsing query","Detail":"QueryParserError: Invalid content. Lexical error at line 1, column 1.  Encountered: \"{\" (123), after : \"\"","code":"4000"}],"type":"ValidationFault"},"time":"2021-05-01T09:10:23.563-07:00"}
```

To me it looks like some syntax error, but not sure where it is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, it was because of URL
I was using this:

```
https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/462081dsfdsfsfds550/query?minorversion=56
```

instead of

```
https://sandbox-quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/462081dsfdsfsfds550/invoice?minorversion=56
```